# Windows Live Writer and LaTeX

Tags: latex, wordpress, windows-live-writer

I am looking for a way to integrate a WordPress latex plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latex/

and Windows Live Writer, so that LaTeX would render in real time in Windows Live Writer.

Any other ways to integrate LaTeX and WLW?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [LaTex plugin for Windows Live Writer](http://code.google.com/p/wlwlatex/).  Don't know if it's any good, but it may be a start.